# Why does this.selectedIndex not work on IE7 for a <select> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-7

This bit of HTML and Javascript works in IE6, FF2 and FF3. I can't find any reason why it shouldn't work in IE7 also, but this.selectedIndex always returns 0.

```
** in javascript file
function onTypeChange()
{
    alert($('type_id').selectedIndex);
    if ($('type_id').selectedIndex != 0) 
    { 
        Element.update('chosenType', this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);     
        Form.Element.enable('go_button'); 
    } else {
        Element.update('chosenType', 'Selected Type'); 
        Form.Element.disable('go_button');
    }
}

** in html
<select class="hosp_select_buttons selectbox" id="type_id" name="type[id]" 
        onchange="onTypeChange();">
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="1594">Ambulatory Surgical Center</option>
<option value="1595">Birthing Center</option>
<option value="1596">Comprehensive Outpatient Rehabilitation Facilities</option>
<option value="1597">Drug Abuse Treatment Program</option>
<option value="1598">Mammography</option>
<option value="1599">Narcotic Treatment Program</option>
<option value="1600">Outpatient Physical Therapy</option>
<option value="1601">Private Home Care Provider</option></select>
```

** Edited to change the stylistic things people objected so strongly too. The alert still says the selectedIndex is 0 after I change the select box. This code has, and still does work in all browsers other than I.E. 7

Comment: Does any of the that JS work? I've never seen that much JS put into an onchange. Usually it's attached otherwise or put into a function.

Comment: Remind you of http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/OnClick-Does-What!.aspx ?

Comment: because 2 lines of javascript == 30 lines of form validation code?

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to get `selectedIndex` from the option list.

Use `this.selectedIndex` instead of `this.options.selectedIndex`.

Also see this example for cleaner usage: http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tutorial002.html

Comment: That was what I had at first, it didn't work either. I've been trying all kinds of things, including getting the select tag explicitly through $('type_id') and this.selectedIndex instead of this.options.selectedIndex

Comment: Interesting. That should definitely work. So if you simply use: onchange="alert(this.selectedIndex);" you don't get the correct result? I don't have IE7 installed, but IE8 and the IE7 compatibility mode show the correct result. You might want to try disabling Prototype to see if that's interfering.

Comment: Just tried the example page I linked to in IE7 in VPC and it worked there. Note that their method is using document.getElementById().

Comment: This code clearly should work - I'm trying to find some sort of weird conflict in jquery or prototype

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I can't help seeing it here unaswered. I think the problem here is that you're using $('type_id'), which returns an Element in jquery (I believe). To access the actual HTML element you have to use $('type_id')[0] or something like that. I think if you use document.getElementById('type_id') it should work.

**Edit:** Changed answer to reflect Benxamin's comment about how to access the dom element $('type_id')[0]

Comment: I wish I still had the code to test this out for sure but I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. To access the first element of the jQuery object, use var el = $('#type_id')[0]  and that will return the HTML DOM element, so that you can use el.options[el.selectedIndex].value.